# Using an aggregate function as part of an expression

Tags: sql

Simple question, I assume it is impossible to use an aggregate function as part of an expression but here is basically what I want to do:

```
SELECT ((Sum(RESOURCES.[Hours Spent]*EMPLOYEES.[Employee Rate])) 
+ GRANTS.Overhead) AS [Estimated Development Cost]
FROM GRANTS 
INNER JOIN 
(EMPLOYEES 
INNER JOIN RESOURCES ON EMPLOYEES.[Employee Number] = RESOURCES.[Employee Number]) 
ON GRANTS.[Grant Program Number] = RESOURCES.[Grant Program Number];
```

It works perfectly before I try to add that last value to it (Grants.Overhead). How could I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: As is, it was receiving an error and wouldn't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `Grants.Overhead` in a separate query, as it counts only once per group. So here you go:

```
SELECT T1.EDC + GRANTS.Overhead AS [Estimated Development Cost]
FROM   (SELECT   RESOURCES.[Grant Program Number] AS GPN,
             (Sum(RESOURCES.[Hours Spent] * EMPLOYEES.[Employee Rate])) AS EDC
    FROM     EMPLOYEES
             INNER JOIN
             RESOURCES
             ON EMPLOYEES.[Employee Number] = RESOURCES.[Employee Number]
    GROUP BY RESOURCES.[Grant Program Number]) AS T1
   INNER JOIN
   GRANTS
   ON GRANTS.[Grant Program Number] = T1.GPN;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum() the overhead too, otherwise you will get the old "it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" error.

This works:

```
SELECT ((Sum(RESOURCES.[Hours Spent]*EMPLOYEES.[Employee Rate])) + sum(GRANTS.Overhead)) AS [Estimated Development Cost]
FROM GRANTS 
INNER JOIN (EMPLOYEES 
            INNER JOIN RESOURCES ON EMPLOYEES.[Employee Number] = RESOURCES.[Employee Number]) 
ON  GRANTS.[Grant Program Number] = RESOURCES.[Grant Program Number];
```